# JavaScript Verificar mail que contenga un @

Tags: javascript, html, array, string

que permita cargar una dirección de mail (el mail sería un texto cargado desde un prompt y asignado a una variable).

Implementar una función que verifique si el string (el texto del mail) contiene el carácter @ (pero uno sólo), si es así informar que está ok, sino informar que es incorrecto.

Esto es lo que realice pero no funciona.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
       <title>Validacion de Mail </title>
       <script src= 'Funciones.js'> </script>
      </head>
      <body>
            <script>

             var mail ;
             mail= document.write((prompt("Ingrese su mail: " , "[en un formato valido]"));
             
             if verificamail false {
             
             document.write("Su mail: " + mail + " es valido: <b> " + verificamail (mail) );
             } else 
             { 
             document.write("Su mail: " + mail + " no es valido: <b> " + verificamail (mail) );
             </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

y este el js

```
function verificamail (a) {
       console.log(a.includes('@'));       // true
       console.log(a.includes('@@', 1));    // false
       console.log(a.includes('@@@@', 1));    // false
   }
```

Comment: Para estos casos creo que lo que buscas es una expresión regular

Answer (score 0):

No funciona porque tiene bastantes errores. Te dejo un código funcional para que lo revises.

```js
var mail;

// pedir datos con el prompt
// lo que se ingresa en el promt se guarda en una variable
mail = prompt("Ingrese su mail: [en un formato valido]");



if (verificamail(mail)) {
  document.write("Su mail: " + mail + " es valido: <b> ");
} else {
  document.write("Su mail: " + mail + " no es valido <b> ");
}


function verificamail(a) {
  // quitar las @ la cadena
  // si la diferencia entre las cadenas es 1 caracter
  // es porque solo hay una @
  return a.length - a.replaceAll("@", "").length == 1;
}
```

Comment: pero en el codigo si coloco 2 @@ igual me sigue marcando como valido el mail. necesito que si en el prompt hay mas de un @ marque no valido.

Comment: Cierto, ya lo corregí.